# Solve equations to get the expression for specific varible

Tags: equation-solving

I have 3 equations as bleow.
    $$
eq1: \frac{\text{f1} \text{x1}}{\text{x2}}=\frac{\text{m1} \text{y1}}        {\text{m2}}\\
eq2:\text{x1}=\frac{\text{m1}}{\text{m1}+\frac{1000}{\text{Ms}}}\\
eq3:\frac{\text{x2}}{\text{m2}}=\lim_{\text{m2}\to 0} \, \frac{1}{\text{m2}+\frac{1000}{\text{Ms}}}
$$

Then y1 shoudl be derived from the 3 equations as 
    $$
\text{y1}=1000 \text{f1} (\text{m1} \text{Ms}+1000)
$$

The code I have is

```
eq1 = f1 x1/(x2) == y1 m1/(m2)
eq2 = x1 == m1/(m1 + 1000/Ms)
eq3 = x2/m2 == Limit[1/(m2 + 1000/Ms), m2 -> 0]
Solve[{eq1, eq2, eq3}, y1]
```

But I cannot get the expected answer. Then I tried the code below but it still not working.

```
Solve[{eq1}, y1] /. {x1 -> m1/(m1 + 1000/Ms), x2/m2 -> Limit[1/(m2 + 1000/Ms), m2 -> 0]}
```

Then I tried to obtain the express for x2 first.

```
Solve [x2/m2 == Limit[1/(m2 + 1000/Ms), m2 -> 0], x2]
```

Then

```
eq1 = f1 x1/(x2) == y1 m1/(m2)
Solve[{eq1}, y1] /. {x1 -> m1/(m1 + 1000/Ms), x2 -> (m2 Ms)/1000}
```

Then I got

```
{{y1 -> (1000 f1)/((m1 + 1000/Ms) Ms)}}
```

Finally I can get the result. But I am wondering if there is a better way to get the result?

Comment: Since there are three equations, there should be three unknowns. To get y1, simply do `y1/.Solve[{eq1, eq2, eq3}, {y1, x1, x2}][[1]]`. This is what you want right?

Comment: @AnjanKumar Thanks! This is what I want!